# Why can't iPhone 4s connect to a specific IP address?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

I built a robot a while ago that I control via the iPhone ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DtornTFcIfk)).

The robot connects to a WiFi hotspot and the iPhone 3Gs would connect to it via Safari and I'd control it from there.  Now that I've upgraded to iPhone 4s, Safari simply won't connect to the IP address stating "Cannot open page".

I can't figure out why.  Every other device in the house connects to the robot fine. How can I debug this?

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the IP I can tell you that. I've got Transmission's web client set up to manage torrents on my Mac and Mobile Safari connects to it just fine.

Comment: What was the answer? I'm having a similar problem here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284762/iphone-and-ipad-suddenly-cant-access-local-ips Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan I honestly don't remember the specifics.  It was a long time ago, but I do remember that it was something stupid I missed and it worked after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your new iPhone is connected to the same WiFi access point?

Try turning both Airplane mode and WiFi ON in Settings to make sure you are accessing the correct local network.

Comment: Yep, that's the first thing I did.

Comment: Have you double checked if you entered the correct subnet mask?